# Make wvidial as network manager default

Tags: networking, gnome, wvdial

My question is, how can I make wvdial my default network app on Ubuntu since my modem can connect through wvdial but not network manager? I can't update it through the GUI if I'm using wvdial.

Due to my modem's incompatibility with `nm-applet`, I'm forced to use `wvdial` on my system. Is there a way I can set `wvdial` to act as my default network manager, effectively replacing the builtin Network Manager?